# How can I make a function work only for desktops and not for mobiles?

Tags: plugins

I'd like this simple echo function would work only for desktops or tablets, I mean screens not so little, and avoid it to work on mobiles. Which is the best solution?

```
echo do_shortcode('[meta_gallery_slider arrows="false" show_caption="false" show_title="false" autoplay="false" slider_height="450"]');
```

Comment: You can't _reliably_ run PHP code only for desktops/mobiles. Your best bet would be to hide the result with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does have a helper function for detecting mobile devices, [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) (untested):

```php
if  ( ! wp_is_mobile() ) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[meta_gallery_slider arrows="false" show_caption="false" show_title="false" autoplay="false" slider_height="450"]' ); 
}
```

As Jacob Peattie mentioned, this is unreliable. Better option is to use CSS to show the output only for viewport widths above specified value (untested):

PHP:

```php
printf( 
    '<div class="hide-if-mobile">%s</div>', 
    do_shortcode( '[meta_gallery_slider arrows="false" show_caption="false" show_title="false" autoplay="false" slider_height="450"]' ) 
);
```

CSS:

```css
@media ( max-width: 768px ) {
    .hide-if-mobile { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: The function works but I'm only realizing now that my question wasn't accurate. When I asked not to make the function work on cell phones, I meant that the function works with its default settings. To be more concrete: if I connect from the desktop the height of the image must be 600 px, if instead I connect from a mobile it must be 200 px (this seems to me to be the default setting). how could I change the CSS? Also an image ratio 800/600 could fit

Comment: @AndreaSacconi Please ask a separate question. You can reference this question if you deem it to be helpful.